# favicon icon not found in IE 11

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, favicon

I tried to execute my web page on chrome, firefox and IE but when I tried to load it in IE the page thrown 404 not found error, favicon.ico not found.

I am unable to find the reason why the error is thrown only on IE?

please suggest how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you show how you define it in html?

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/favicon.ico" />

Comment: Is it in the `<head>`? Also try adding `type="image/x-icon"` to it

Comment: yes it is in head section and I also tried by adding type="image/x-icon", but I get same result